# Paperclip failed to upload msg file type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, msg, paperclip-validation

I need to attach the msg file to rails, i have add the mime type for the msg filetype

```
validates_attachment :file, content_type: { content_type: ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif", "application/pdf","application/vnd.ms-excel",     
         "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
         "application/msword",
         "application/vnd.ms-outlook", 
         "application/octet-stream",
         "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", 
         "text/plain"] }
```

but when upload with the sample msg file it went error

```
Command :: file -b --mime '/tmp/5e8ff9bf55ba3508199d22e984129be620170527-6239-gqgnhz.msg'
Command :: file -b --mime '/tmp/5e8ff9bf55ba3508199d22e984129be620170527-6239-g903st.msg'
(0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 26ms (ActiveRecord: 1.7ms)
```

any suggestion? i am using paperclip 5.1.0

Answer (score 0):

what is the rails validation error?

```
if object.save
  ... 
else 
  logger.debug object.errors.inspect 
end
```

Read the save error that cause rollback, from there you'll know the reason it were rejected.